# Import database backup (.bak file) into another database

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm using microsoft SQL server. I have a database that we can call database1 and its backup in .bak format.
I need to restore the backup to another, blank database that we can call database_temp, so both database must exist. I need to get and confirm some data from the database_temp archive and then delete it when I'll end my job.

what I did:

1) created new database "database_blank"

2) tasks - restore database. In source I choose "device" and then my .bak file, in destination I select database_temp.

3) in option I choose Overwrite the existing database with replace.

I got the error "Restore of database failed the file cannot be overwritten it is being used by database1 database"

Comment: kill all the connections (spids)

Comment: @DougCoats problem isn't the connections, it's the files. Dan_Hero, when you restore a database, it'll default to the name of the files that the original database had, not the one you're overwriting. you need to change the names of the files in the Files Pane to be those of the `Database_Temp` database. I *assume those would be `Database_temp.mdb` and `Database_Temp_log.ldf` for the data and row files respectively, but you'll need to check.

Comment: Maybe a dupplicate of this subject
[https://serverfault.com/questions/244665/mdf-file-cannot-be-overwritten-when-restoring-a-database-in-sql-server/916032](https://serverfault.com/questions/244665/mdf-file-cannot-be-overwritten-when-restoring-a-database-in-sql-server/916032)

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the database files.

e.g.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks] FROM DISK = 'c:\backup\Adv.bak'
WITH CHECKSUM,
MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Data' TO 'c:\mssql\data\AdventureWorksCopy_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'AdventureWorks_Log' TO 'c:\mssql\log\AdventureWorksCopy_Log.ldf',
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

The first part of the move is the logical file name of the database file. Right click on the original database - Properties - Files to get the right names.

The full documented syntax can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)